# CSS Grids. Different gap between each grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to apply different gap between each grid element, for example we are having the following code. 4 Grid lines, 3 Elements and a 10px width between each grid-box. How can i apply custom width between each grid-box? for example 20px between element1 and element2, and then 30px between element2 and element3?

Can i achieve that with the CSS grids?

Edit: Without using padding.
Edit2: Provided Picture.

[Click for picture preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HqYG.jpg)

```css
html, body {height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-row: 1fr 1fr;
grid-column-gap: 10px;
grid-row-gap: 10px;
 
}
#element1 {
grid-column: 1/2;
grid-row: 1/2; 
border: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
color: #000;
}

#element2 {
grid-column: 2/3;
grid-row: 1/2; 
border: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
color: #000;
}

#element3 {
grid-column: 3/4;
grid-row: 1/2; 
border: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="element1">element1</div>
<div id="element2">element2</div>
<div id="element3">element3</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well the general approach that I like to use with css-grid is to make extra columns. Obviously use `grid-column-gap` and `grid-row-gap` if you have the same padding, but if not you can add token columns.

## Why not padding/ margin?

You can totally use padding/ margin for this, but I like the extra column a bit better, since in css-grid you define the layout in the wrapper and this is where this belongs to semantically. You also do not have to apply it to every single item in those columns. (Also, do you apply it to the left or the right or both items?).

## But this messes up my numbering

Yes, that is why you **never use numbers to describe an area in css grid!**

You can name your lines and with it your areas. Use this! You can use the `grid-template-areas` for this ore simply name it like this:

```
grid-template-columns: [left-start] auto [left-end right-start] auto [right-end];
```

Oh you want extra padding? Here you go:

```
grid-template-columns: [left-start] auto [left-end] 10px [right-start] auto [right-end];
```

---

Note that I am by no means a seasoned web developer (quite the opposite), but I think this approach might - generally - be the best one.

Comment: What do you mean by 'make extra columns'? You add empty columns like <div></div>?

Comment: Like what I showed in the example at the end. Without names, originally it was `auto auto`, but then I added another column in the middle so the CSS is `auto 10px auto`
`<div></div>` does *not* necessarily add an empty column when you use css-grid. By default it will automatically fill the next column, but as I described in my answer, you should use names to specify the columns e.g. `grid-area: left;`.

Comment: This is a nice reference for css-grids: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Ok this technique works nicely, and keeps number source-of-truth in one place (which IMHO is the most important), rather than wrestling with padding/margin at different places. I use this in the case where I want custom column gap's per column, instead of using a blanket `gap:x`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything specific on [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) for your case, but you can easily achieve the desired result by adding padding.

**HTML**

```
<div id="grid">
  <div id="element1">
    <div class="content">element1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="element2">
    <div class="content">element2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="element3">
    <div class="content">element3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#element1 {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#element2 {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#element3 {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
}
```

---

JsFiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/wkt39kk8/

Comment: Yes, i can give padding, however somehow i am not achieving the desired result in my layout. Maybe i should use another approach? Can i ask what is the best practice for layouts at the moment?

Comment: What's the problem you're facing with paddings?

Comment: I have alot of elements and a lot of grids. For the sake of explaining the problem i simply made a few grids here in order to ask. In my layout i have a few images which are inside a few divs, one is even having a frame over the picture, and he frame itself is overflowing in the oher grid. Here's why im searching for a way to make some space between them. Padding didnt work as expected, i gave it 30px padding but it padded only with 20px. Then i went and sinply tried pad with 200px. And again it only moved with 20px. I am sorry that i cant provide a screenshot atm.

Comment: @Knightwalker, you should provide all these details in your question, and post enough code to reproduce the actual problem. If you want help for a specific problem, ask a specific question.

Comment: It is specific! I am searching for a way to add custom width between 3 grids. This is all the code that is needed to reproduce the problem!

Comment: @Knightwalker, what Michael_B is trying to say is that your problem lies somewhere else. It's not the space between the grid. So even though I answered your question correctly, it has nothing to do with you solving your problem. I can only suggest you to try replacing paddings with margins in the inner element, like so: #element1 .content { margin-right: 5px; } etc...

Comment: Yea, thanks for helping out. @m.spyratos , just that last time i asked inside stackoverflow, some guy helped and the other one just came downvoted everything without looking the code and i got pissed lol. Thats why i reacted like that to Michael. Anyway i tried with the margin and it seems like maybe there isn't enough space. I will provide a picture in my problem, so you can see how it looks like, but then i think i will just use 2 main containers, float them and then use smt like margin between them. Probably a better approach atm i think. Thanks!